# WebDriver, Python: How to catch dynamically updating url with the appropriate value and save it to the variable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, robotframework

python/selenium web driver code:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#username")
elem.send_keys("username")
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#password")
elem.send_keys("password")

driver.implicitly_wait(2) #seconds
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button")
elem.click()

def condition(driver):
    look_for = ("url_which_contains_this_text")
    url = driver.current_url
    for look_for in url:
        if url.find(look_for) != -1:
            print url

    return url

#page_url = driver.current_url
print url
```

In this code:
1) user login;
2) click 'login button';
And then I need to catch somehow the URL  which is dynamically changing
every second (access token loaded, etc), and catch the URL which 
contains value "example_id=" and save this url to variable and print.

Сan someone help me ?

Comment: you want to define actual webpage url that opens after successful authorization?

Comment: After clicking login button there are couple URL's returned before the dashboard page is loaded. I need to catch one of them, which will contain "example_id=" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that this will work as I cannot test it, but you may try something like this:

```
required_url = ""
while True:
    current_url = driver.current_url
    if "example_id=" in current_url:
        required_url = current_url
        print('\n'+required_url)
        break
    else: print(current_url)
```

Comment: Not bad solution, but...problem that target_url is the dynamic URL, which is generated dynamically. And I don't have the static value of this URL.

Comment: So leave just first `if` operator :)

Comment: Okay, when I use this part of code (first if). it returns nothing. and I cannot print nothing.

"nameError: name 'current_url' is not defined"

Comment: It's still requires small fixes, but it works! thanks a lot :)